# Randomly choose positions of turtle circles without overlap

Tags: python, random, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

If I used `randint()` to choose the positions of turtle circles, how do I make sure they don't overlap.  Here is my code for one circle. The screen has to be 500 x 500 pixels and the circles have to be 35 pixels:

```
asteroid.pencolor('grey')
asteroid.fillcolor('grey')
asteroid.begin_fill()
asteroid.hideturtle()
asteroid.penup()
asteroid.speed(15)
asteroid.setposition(randint(-400,400), randint(-400,400))
asteroid.pendown()
asteroid.circle(35)
asteroid.end_fill()
```

Comment: You could choose random positions in different quadrants of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, your claim that "The screen has to be 500,500" and your use of the value -400/400 in the following:

```
setposition(randint(-400,400), randint(-400,400))
```

seem to be in conflict as a 500 x 500 screen implies `randint(-250, 250)`

Moving on, you can achieve your goal by testing each new asteroid against the locations of the others using something like `any` and `turtle.distance()`:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle
from random import randint

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500
ASTEROID_RADIUS = 35
NUMBER_ASTEROIDS = 50
CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)

asteroid_prototype = Turtle()
asteroid_prototype.hideturtle()
asteroid_prototype.color('grey')
asteroid_prototype.shape('circle')
asteroid_prototype.shapesize(ASTEROID_RADIUS / CURSOR_SIZE)
asteroid_prototype.speed('fastest')  # because 15 isn't a valid argument
asteroid_prototype.penup()

asteroids = []

for _ in range(NUMBER_ASTEROIDS):
    asteroid = asteroid_prototype.clone()
    asteroid.setposition( \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
        randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
    )

    while any(map((lambda a: lambda b: a.distance(b) < ASTEROID_RADIUS)(asteroid), asteroids)):
        asteroid.setposition( \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - WIDTH/2, WIDTH/2 - ASTEROID_RADIUS), \
            randint(ASTEROID_RADIUS - HEIGHT/2, HEIGHT/2 - ASTEROID_RADIUS) \
        )

    asteroid.showturtle()
    asteroids.append(asteroid)

screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I changed some of the code to work better in my game but kept the main mechanics.